# Cloud Vision API size between text for bounding box

Tags: c#, google-cloud-vision

I am currently using the API to scan document and the API itself should be using the distance between text to separate the sections and it should be something like a box to surround the text sections and now I want the bounding boxes that created by the API itself to be adjust by myself, is that possible to do in C#? Because I been looking for the solution and sees that in python with this API it is possible to use functions to draw the bounding boxes ourselves.